# Java wildcard is interface

Tags: java, android, interface

I have the following method:

```
protected <T> T castToInterface(Class<T> tClass, Context parent) {
    try { return tClass.cast(parent); }
    catch (ClassCastException e) {
        throw new ClassCastException(String.valueOf(parent)
                + " must implement " + tClass.getSimpleName());
    }
}
```

Wile the method does it's job, I am curious, would it be possible to do the equivalent of

```
protected <T extends interface> T castToInterface(...
```

so that the method only accepts classes that are interfaces?

Comment: No ... but you can use "empty" interface ... like `public interface IInterface {}` and all ifaces should extends  it ...

Comment: http://ideone.com/nCS3WA